# What did this character hit to cause the massive explosion?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse, marvel

In the movie X-Men Apocalypse we see,

> When Apocalypse infiltrates the Mansion to abduct Prof. Xavier, Alex tries to save him with his laser blasts. But Apocalypse teleports away, causing Alex to hit something which causes a huge explosion destroying the building.

This sequence was quite fast, so I couldn't understand what did he hit. Was it the Jet or some secret stash of explosives ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looked like the beam hit the engine of the jet that Beast was showing off earlier (as seen in the trailers, and shown below).

[image: image from X-Men: Apocalypse trailer]

[MoviePilot](http://moviepilot.com/posts/3928530)'s spoiler-filled review/plot synopsis says that the X-Jet is nuclear powered, and confirms it is what fuelled the explosion.

Comment: Guess it won't be possible to get our hands on a screenshot yet.. Sigh..

Comment: well, this does explain a lot. I will wait for a while to see if anyone has some other source, else yours is the answer.